# How can i generate Walking or Driving static google map

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to create a google map using the static google map API. I want walking and driving static map.

Bellow is the path i am using : 
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&zoom=14&size=400x250&markers=color:green|label:A|30.7261629,76.7596221&markers=color:red|label:B|30.7226447,76.7681678&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:3|30.7261629,76.7596221|30.7226447,76.7681678&sensor=false

Comment: What you have tried, can you provide the code you tried?

Comment: I am trying to show the map by just using the path :  http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?maptype=roadmap&zoom=14&size=400x250&markers=color:green|label:A|30.7261629,76.7596221&markers=color:red|label:B|30.7226447,76.7681678&path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:3|30.7261629,76.7596221|30.7226447,76.7681678&sensor=false

Comment: Can you modify this path in such a way that it can generate a map with driving route from A to B. ?

Comment: related question: [google maps static map polyline passing throught lakes, river, mountains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32255380/google-maps-static-map-polyline-passing-throught-lakes-river-mountains/32257219#32257219)

Answer (score 1):

Static map api support only marker not direction.

If you want to use direction with Static map, you need to use direction api.

How to do: [how to create a static api map with directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136892/how-to-create-a-static-api-map-with-directions)

Basically what the up-voted answer is saying:

```
1. Use direction api to get encoded path.
2. In static map use this encoded path.
```

Comment: Thanks, now i am able to generate a static driving map url.

Comment: But when i am using this as src of <img> in tcpdf, it is showing wrong path.

Comment: May be due to the characters in enc : in path

Comment: url with encrypted and special characters is not getting parsed well in tcpdf. Can you check this