# How to convert Google maps div to image using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, css, html, google-maps

I need to send HTML email to customer which contains Google maps (with directions) using java script or c# 
Example: Uber Call taxi sends to customer invoice with google maps  as html mail
[Uber Html Invoice with google maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJw1w.png)

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/

Comment: No, i am expecting to show directions between two location but Google static maps API not supporting directions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Static Maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/

An example would be something like this:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=800x600&maptype=hybrid&scale=2&format=png8&sensor=false&path=geodesic%3Atrue%7C-6.9325%2C+37.3916666666667%7C-6.9325%2C+37.3933333333333%7C-6.93388888888889%2C+37.3933333333333%7C-6.93388888888889%2C+37.3916666666667%7C-6.9325%2C+37.3916666666667&zoom=10" width="800" height="600"/>
```

Comment: No, i am expecting to show directions between two location but Google static maps API not supporting directions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [screen capture feature of PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) to capture html page and save it as .jpg or .png image on a server. Then you can include the image in your invoice that you send out to users. PhantomJs commands can be saved as a .bat file and triggered via C# code.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way to use the static API and add in an additional encoded polyline.

Example url [here](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&path=enc%3AsizwFsq_z@Lg@j@o@bASbBLpCt@n@%5El@x@%5CN~Cd@nHCn@EdDdDv@n@lG%7CAgBhFUrADn@Zx@hMfStF%7CIvBrDl@dEJxBMlEG%60CVjBv@lEPjBIbAM%60@GAMDKNBh@JLBLa@lD@zD%60@rCzApFxBvJtEfVZdEq@fBaAZi@Ik@_@%7DBsB%7DBuA%7BAa@_Gw@oDNwBf@wEjCo@n@gErE%7DLdNqIfKeBpCoApCy@dCwArFgC%60RaD%7COmAnE%7BDpIcDvFeDdEmDxDkD%60CwG~Dyg@tUwJzFy@p@kExEcLrPiDrCaDbBwFlC_F%60EuAlBiB%7CDiA%60Eg@tCm@pHErFbApPFpDGpA_@~Dc@vBwAhEyDzIeBzDsBvC_A~@eC%60B_C%7C@aDd@%7DHGsKAsGDsDXsDv@uEjBiCbBmE~DaDzDqG%60IyFnGqFdFoHvEqHtC_PnEeF~AoFxBgGxDkFtE%7DGnJqCxF%7DAbEcBnGyAxGsBjKoGn%5CoBtIwCrJyApD_EnIyGzKmNlTyJzNsClDiF~EkI%7CFuAx@wIlFwJ%7CFiH%60FwGdFgJbI%7BNbNmGdGqH%60IiEpFaExGqDnHoBfFyCtJwBxIoJ%60d@iHhWqIpU%7BPzc@aCtF%7DFlJcHdHwF%7CDgH%7CCqWxGqElByDxBsFhEwClDi%5Dnb@%7BDdEkMxKoBbB_A%60A%7B@%5CaACc@%5BSc@GkAR%7B@l@g@%7C@@pAhAjAtAlBzBlE%60GfB~CdElHpXpf@hZzh@hEzHdEfFzIdIrWpU%60fA~_A%60FlGdChEnBlEdHdTdJbY%7CFtQ~BxIpExSlBrJ%7CAbGjAbDxAbDhAzB~C~ErAhBdDhDvDrDlFjHnD%7CHvBjHz%5CfqAxEzP%60CzJ~@%60FjAjIjAbNd@dGfBnUpApWdAxVvAp%5DbAlLnAxGbAnDbBvElB%7CDxCzHfBdIXtBt@~JH~GKxGBhJ%5ExDnAfHdCtL%5ExDZ%60I_@vWq@bXQ%7CKDxF%60ArMnBhRhBxJpErMfIjTfCbInBdJdCfPdAhH%60Lzw@hBlHpD%7CIlB%60DbEfFtIxIdClCte@hf@%7CTrUxFxIrBfFvA%60FnAhGlAbJ%7CBtQdBbIrB~F%7CHjN%7CNrVdG~J%7CJ%60QfK%7CPpDfGtIjPhAxBv_@du@~Rb%60@lL%60VvD%60Lh@%60Ct@lDfAjHl@jGTfEPzNWbLc@zGqBfRiFjd@yApROdHDdK%7CDpw@bD~n@dCbg@tAtU~Dxs@x@xG%60BpJtAvFP%7CBGjAw@r@sDOwBU%7D@Uo@MM%60@_@%60BaCtQc@pAsFzGiC%7CDgD%60F%5BLIJEZgA%7CDwB~EmAxAa@Vu@HoAd@w@%7CA) results in the following image:

[image: Example image]

Basically you have to generate a dynamic JS map and parse the result looking for a tag called "overview_polyline". This field is then sent in to the static map generator to add the line on top of the map.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23937276/1581477

More info on polylines: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility

Comment: In your scenario we must have n - number of latitude and longitudes it is not possible with only two latitude and longitudes(source location to destination)

Comment: @DIneshAG I'm not sure I follow you here. What is it you want to have n number of? Previously you wrote "...show directions between two locations" which would work with my answer above.

Comment: In your Url static map api Path is encoded so the encoded path contains nearly 20 latitude and longitudes, see in your URL link   "size=400x400&path=enc".    Example after enc in url embedded like this "<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&amp;sensor=false&amp;path=color:0xff0000ff|weight:5|51.511333,-0.119355|51.506205,-0.114462|51.507774,-0.10861|51.507801,-0.107569|51.5071,-0.107344|51.507207,-0.105016|51.507507,-0.104404|51.510999,-0.104297">"