# Google Static Map Doesn't Show Directions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I couldn't able to show up the route directions between my markers on static map.

I have run through [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38302858/google-static-maps-with-directions) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136892/how-to-create-a-static-api-map-with-directions) and finalize my URL as below:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=41.0933217,29.0924325&size=357x632&markers=color:red%7Clabel:1%7C41.0933217,29.0924325&markers=color:red%7Clabel:2%7C41.0928494,29.0964868&path=color:0xff0000ff|enc:ezxyFs_rpDyC[s@WI?UDa@l@YP{@PUD@JAb@Xd@DHGNKf@EX@JCRSHOFQCIVMTRJD^@FLCRlBPzBPDrAb@z@\\LBAHGlAMbC?`@?a@Du@N{C@IMC{@]sAc@QEQ{BSmBMBAGE_@SKVm@PBNGRIBSAS@IH]La@_@o@?o@dASXKVUTa@NEH?PBf@Rh@dALb@B`@&key=[KEY]
```

On the image, only markers could be seen. I have also checked my encoded polyline through [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility). I copy and paste my polyline (which I get from https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions) on "Encoded Polyline" section on that page, and it successfully creates directions.

I can't figure out what I am missing.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have some incorrect values in your encoded polyline, I've recreated the Static Maps URL request below:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=41.0933217,29.0924325&size=357x632&markers=color:red%7Clabel:1%7C41.0933217,29.0924325&markers=color:red%7Clabel:2%7C41.0928494,29.0964868&path=color:0xff0000ff|enc:{|xyFe|qpDHx@ZLvBz@nA`@`AXWvAAPONGDMBkB}@_B}@QEY?{E{BSOY[[g@WUUGa@Ea@DS@W?a@IoDw@oCc@qC[eEk@yCc@e@@Q`@GLETCXB\HXJPTNVF\?xBO`BCjCFtCRLADEj@b@p@z@fBjCj@|@VNJBr@Fn@VZ`@FHHZJ~@@r@OjAGv@GzB?dCEjBPLxAh@NBVCDAe@uEJ[Hi@RuD@c@`@Nf@TEd@GhAEdAC|@&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

In order to prevent errors when creating encoded polyline, you may use the [Directions Calculator](https://directionsdebug.firebaseapp.com/) then after you enter the desired locations, click "JSON" in the upper right then copy the encoded polyline under "overview_polyline" then include it on your Static Maps URL.